# Reactifying buttons? Sharing functions between similar buttons?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn Reactjs better by refactoring my app and splitting up functions. I currently have buttons that require a different function for each property I modify but I think that's really inefficient if the same logic is applying. I want the button functions to be reusable where I can programmatically pass property values to the button that can be modified. I don't know the Reactjs terminology enough to be able to google it so I built a JsFiddle example of my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/5vznejyx/

Sorry if the dayjs complicates this, a simple counter example would of worked too.

I've tried different syntax variations of the onClick to try and get it to pass the property into the function but I get strange errors in any case:

The function:

```
  minusOneHrFunc = (input) => {
    this.setState({
      input: dayjs().subtract(1, 'hour').format('YYYY-MM-DD-hh:mm:ssA'),
    })

  }
```

```
onclick={this.minusOneHrFunc(this.state.startDate)} //errors

onclick={this.minusOneHrFunc({startDate})} //not defined

onclick={this.minusOneHrFunc(this.state.startDate).bind(this} //infinite loops if this.setState is in the function
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: just post the code of  minusOneHrFunc in your topic

Comment: @DmitryReutov added!

Answer (score 0):

Define a click handler function on your component:

```
  clickHandle = (props) => {
    console.log("Clicked");  
  }
```

And call it inside your button like this and pass any props to it:

```
<button onClick={()=>this.clickHandle()} />
```

Comment: But I am trying to learn how I can pass different properties into reusable functions and manipulate their state, I'm not sure how this correlates to that.

Answer (score 0):

Writing this

```
onclick={this.minusOneHrFunc(this.state.startDate)}
```

Will execute the function after rendering before even button click

It should be

```
onclick={() => this.minusOneHrFunc(this.state.startDate)}
```

Comment: How does the function set state logic look for this? Is there a special syntax for having the setState programmatically intake different properties / variables?

Comment: when you declare a component literal in JSX, the values inside the curly braces are evaluated immediately. So `<Foo bar={new Date()} />` will create a Foo component with the current date of when the component was created. (recall that JSX component compile to `createComponent calls, and just like other function calls, arguments are evaluated before the function is called). In order to delay something in javascript, you can wrap it in a function, and then later call that function. That's how handlers behave, they expect that a function will be passed to them and then call it later.

Comment: `this.minusOneHrFunc(this.state.startDate)` calls `this.minusOneHrFunc` and returns it's value, which gets passed to the `onclick` prop. `() => this.minusOneHrFunc(this.state.startDate)` creates a function and passes that function to the `onclick` prop (without calling the function).

Comment: That makes sense but I'm not quite understanding the syntax on how to programmatically pass the property into the targeted function. I'm able to get a console.log to work but not the this.setState as seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/1aenx9v0/14/ the input positional seems to be treated as a key

Answer (score 0):

Solved this after building a small counter example with help from this post: [Reactjs passing different properties to the same function with similar buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58420134/reactjs-passing-different-properties-to-the-same-function-with-similar-buttons)

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Vallamost/mktuq53j/7/

code:

```
class FunctionReuse extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      countValue: 0,
      dateEnd: dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD-hh:mm:ss'),
      dateStart: dayjs().subtract(4, 'hour').format('YYYY-MM-DD-hh:mm:ss')

    }

  }

  minusOneHrFunc = (input) => {

        var { target: { name, value } } = event

    this.setState({
        [name] : dayjs(this.state[name]).subtract(1, 'hour').format('YYYY-MM-DD-hh:mm:ss')
    });

  }

  addOneHrFunc = (input) => {

        var { target: { name, value } } = event

    this.setState({
        [name] : dayjs(this.state[name]).add(1, 'hour').format('YYYY-MM-DD-hh:mm:ss')
    });

  }

  minusOneDayFunc = (input) => {

        var { target: { name, value } } = event

    this.setState({
        [name] : dayjs(this.state[name]).subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD-hh:mm:ss')
    });

  }

  addOneDayFunc = (input) => {

        var { target: { name, value } } = event

    this.setState({
        [name] : dayjs(this.state[name]).add(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD-hh:mm:ss')
    });

  }


  render(){
    var dateEnd = this.state.dateEnd;

    return(
      <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
          Function reuse learning: 
        </p>
        <form>
        <br/>
        <label>Date Start: {this.state.dateStart}</label> 
        <br/>Adjust time: &nbsp;
        <button type="button" name="dateStart" onClick={this.minusOneHrFunc}>-1hr</button>
        <button type="button" name="dateStart" onClick={this.addOneHrFunc}>+1hr</button>
        <button type="button" name="dateStart" onClick={this.minusOneDayFunc}>-1day</button>
        <button type="button" name="dateStart" onClick={this.addOneDayFunc}>+1day</button>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label>Date End: {this.state.dateEnd}</label>
        <br/>Adjust time: &nbsp;

        <button type="button" name="dateEnd" onClick={this.minusOneHrFunc}>-1hr</button>
        <button type="button" name="dateEnd" onClick={this.addOneHrFunc}>+1hr</button>
        <button type="button" name="dateEnd" onClick={this.minusOneDayFunc}>-1day</button>
        <button type="button" name="dateEnd" onClick={this.addOneDayFunc}>+1day</button>
        </form>

        <br/>
        How can I share a function between similar buttons?
      </header>
    </div>

    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<FunctionReuse />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```